# How to select a default frame for `\animategraphics` when the viewer doesn't support animation?

Tags: printing, animate

I made a beamer with some animations. Here is a sample of my code:

```
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \animategraphics[autoplay,loop,width=\textwidth]{2}{../figures/sim_scan/res_scan_sim_}{0}{50}
    \caption{Simulation of the \textit{ScanSAR} mode}
    \label{res_scan_animation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I want to know, is there is a way to **select which frame is displayed** when the pdf **viewer doesn't support animations** or when it is printed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of the `poster` option determines which frame of the animation to print and to display at first. This should work in any pdf viewer.

The default is to show the first frame of the sequence. Alternatively, the last frame can be displayed (`poster=last`) or no frame at all (`poster=none`).

Also, since version `2014/11/25`, any of the animation frames can be specified as the poster frame by supplying an integer to the `poster` option. E. g. `poster=99` displays the 100th frame (frame numbers are 0-based).

---

`poster=first` is default behaviour and does not need be given explicitly.

Comment: Brilliant! Can I set the value of this property to a frame number (e.g. `poster=50`)? I just tried and it displayed nothing.

Comment: @user2482876: This hasn't been implemented yet. I may put it on my tasks list.

Comment: ok, then is there a way to choose the middle frame?

Comment: @user2482876 There will be. One day.

Comment: @AlexG is there a way to specify a completely different image as a poster frame? Something like `poster='myimage.png'`?

Comment: @VitoGentile : Not, so far, sorry. This has yet to be implemented.

Comment: @AlexG Actually I have found a PDF tthat implements exactly this feature. Check [this link](http://www.socialnui.unimelb.edu.au/publications/2016-SocialNUI-Carter.pdf)

Comment: @VitoGentile : Well this is different. It has embedded Flash. You can embed Flash and MP4 video files with the `media9` LaTeX package. With `media9` you *can* select an arbitrary poster image.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you for the answer and for the feature! It is really useful. However I also should point that animation works completely well only for `poster = first` and `poster = last`. Otherwise animation starts from `poster` frame (or from an empty image for `poster = none`). I guess it is not supposed to go this way

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Which frame do you expect the animation to start from? I am unsure. It is hard to meet everyone's needs.

Comment: @Smylic : Now, with the current version, playback starts from the beginning, irrespective of the poster frame setting.